# What is best NoSQL for using Iqueryable in .Net?

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, nosql, ravendb, iqueryable

I want to choose a NoSQL for ASP.NET Core for used to IQueryable. I try Mongo Db and Raven Db but that client's library don't support multi clause as IQueryable. for sample, I need a thing like snippet below code:

```
 query = query.Where(p => p.LastPrice > p.CurrentPrice);
 query = query.Where(p => p.CreatedTme > Datetime.now);
 query = query.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedTime); 
 var list = await query.ToListAsync();
```

For sample, this works in mongo and ravenDb

```
query = query.Where(p => p.LastPrice > 100);
```

But this doesn't works

```
query = query.Where(p => p.LastPrice > p.CurrentPrice);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a general search and tests, eventually i figure out Cosmos DB is best choose. this either is for microsoft and that is comfortable with my scenario.